# Simple horizontal content slider / scroller only with CSS?

Tags: css

**Click this link to see my concept image regarding the subject:** http://i45.tinypic.com/k33c0i.jpg

Hi! Is it possible to do such custom "sliders" for overflowing content without the default Scrollers? It doesn't matter how the actual transition goes (could work just like the regular horizontal scrollbar for i care, just without the ugly default gray buttons/bar). Preferably i would like to do it just with CSS, but if not, i'll consider other ways to do it aswell. Or i'll just simply create another page to the remaining images.

http://www.visioville.fi/en/

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get rid of the scrollbars by setting

```
overflow:hidden
```

in CSS, which will "clip" the DIV contents.

I don't think there is a pure CSS way to scroll it. That is easily doable with [jQuery.ScrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) - just bind hover() or click() events to your arrow icons.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this site, I believe it will be of some use to you. It's what I've used in the past: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Comment: Nice, i'll keep that in mind that's sure. Thanks! I decided that i'll try to do this site with just CSS (atleast that's the current thought), for the experience or whatnot but here i go. Late tomorrow i'm going to lauch the initial version of the site, so friends and other can start commenting.